# Creating a mysql function to manipulate a date

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

I want to create a function in mysql 5.7 which receives two dates and checks if there is a difference. If yes it should add one day to the second date and return it. If not, it should return the date without any manipulation.

Unfortunately I receive a syntax error every time I want to save the function (using TablePlus with full rights).

My function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `CheckCreatedAt`(timeStart DATETIME, timeEnd DATETIME) RETURNS datetime
BEGIN 
    DECLARE newDate DATETIME;

    IF TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timeStart, timeEnd) != 0 
    THEN 
        SET newDate = DATE_ADD(timeEnd, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
​   ELSE 
        SET newDate = timeEnd;
    END IF;

    RETURN newDate;
END
```

The error-message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ELSE        SET newDate = timeEnd;  END IF;
>
> RETURN newDate; END' at line 6

Comment: I don't see any evidence that you are setting delimiters.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Looks like that the problem is an invisible character at the start of the ELSE-line. Remove that and you should be ok.

Comment: I concur with @slaakso copy/paste the code into a decent editor. You have a corruption which show up as `37` a `?` after the `INVERVAL 1 DAY);` and before the `ELSE`

Answer (score 0):

When creating stored procedurs and functions, you need to change the delimiter in order that you can notify MySQL where your code ends.

This is achieved using the `DELIMITER` command. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
```

Will change the delimiter to a double dollar.

Modify your code to the following and it will create your function (barring other syntax errors):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `CheckCreatedAt`(timeStart DATETIME, timeEnd DATETIME) RETURNS datetime
BEGIN 
    DECLARE newDate DATETIME;

    IF TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timeStart, timeEnd) != 0 THEN
        SET newDate = DATE_ADD(timeEnd, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
 ​   ELSE 
        SET newDate = timeEnd;
    END IF;

    RETURN newDate;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This changes the delimiter to `$$`, adds `$$` to the `END` statement of your function, and then reverts the delimiter back to `;` (the default).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler solution to solve this. There is no need to use a additional variable inside the function. You can return the values directly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `CheckCreatedAt`(timeStart DATETIME, timeEnd DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
  IF TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timeStart, timeEnd) <> 0 THEN
    RETURN DATE_ADD(timeEnd, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  ELSE 
    RETURN timeEnd;
  END IF;
END
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b7b04546093b896885dcfac57182332d)

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian, you could simplify the fuction even further. Remove the `IF ELSE` and multiple `RETURN`s and even the `DATE_ADD` (and the `BEGIN/ELSE`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `CheckCreatedAt`(
timeStart DATETIME, 
timeEnd DATETIME
) 
RETURNS DATETIME
RETURN IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timeStart, timeEnd) != 0, timeEnd +INTERVAL 1 DAY, timeEnd);
```